# how to execute PLSQL script from tOracleRow component using Talend?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, talend

I am new to Talend. I am using Talend 6.5.1 version and Oracle 11.
I have created a simple table in Oracle.

**Table DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE test(id NUMBER);
```

Now, I am inserting records with following Talend job flow.

```
tOracleConnection ---On Component Ok ---> tOracleRow_1
```

I am able to insert records by providing PLSQL queries.

**PLSQL queries:**

```
" BEGIN 
 INSERT INTO test(id) values(1);
 INSERT INTO test(id) values(2);
 INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES(3);
 END; "
```

Till this everything is fine.

Now, I want to automate this so that, I will put these PLSQL queries into one text file.
Then, I will read the content of the file as a string and will pass that string to tOracleRow component.

To achieve this, I have prepared the following Talend job flow.

```
    tOracleConnection --- On Component Ok ---> tFileInputRaw(reading PLSQL file) --- 
--- row1(Main) --> tJavaRow(logging purpose) ---row2(Main) ---> tOracleRow_1
```

While executing this job I am getting following SQLException.

> Exception in component tOracleRow_1: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid
> SQL type: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED

If someone already encountered such an issue please provide your suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved.

Actually, in the PLSQL queries file, we don't require enclosed queries with a double-quote.

So, your PLSQL query will look like.

```
 BEGIN 
 INSERT INTO test(id) values(1);
 INSERT INTO test(id) values(2);
 INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES(3);
 END;
```